# What makes a good wireframe tool?

Tags: website-design, wireframe

I saw this on twitter, but I don't know whether the points in this article objectively. I 'm a new PM and want to choose a fine wireframe tool to use. 
Thank you very much!

**What Makes a Good Wireframe Tool?**
Many product managers and UI designers I know believe that, paper prototyping is free and unrestricted. Since every component can be represented by shapes, even those complicated interactions can also be easily showed with arrows and other connections. Thus, compared with using wireframe software, paper prototyping is faster and easier. This is, in fact, an underestimation to our learning ability. Just like driving is, objectively, more difficult than riding a horse, we still can’t say it’s freer to ride. To dig deeply, we find an important concept missing in this thought --- user experience. A draft, which may be able to show interactions, cannot demonstrate the process because the only way to know user experience is to experience, without a single step left. Even in speed, paper prototyping isn’t better than wireframe software, since it takes more time to communicate with developers once there’s only a draft available. Frankly there’ve been more and more PM & UI designers who realize that wireframe tools are irreplaceable. It’s just choosing from these tools that troubled them. Therefore, in this article, I’ll talk about what features make a good wireframe tool in details.

**A Good Wireframe Tool Saves Your Time**
Like I’ve said in the above part, a good wireframe software will never restrict one’s creativity so it worths spending time to study it. However,it’s not a wise choice to spend much time on learning the wireframe software itself. In this way, the first feature that makes a good wireframe tool is to save user’s time. What kind of tools can save users’ time? It’s definitely those with **brief interface, user-friendly operations, convenient, fast demonstration & quick modifications.**  [read more >>](https://twitter.com/imyutingliu/status/834212515152211968)

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

after reading a comment from @JonW I checked if anyone has done a survey on this  and here's what I found:

> Though this category seems like an opportunity to shine for tools like
> **Balsamiq and Omnigraffle which are tailor-made for wireframing**, they
> fail to break into double digits. Participants seem to favor broader
> design tools like Sketch, the winner by far, and Illustrator.
>
> http://tools.subtraction.com/wireframing.html

[image]

---

If you're thinking about Wireframes (not prototyping) then [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/) is the best digital tool.  It's interface is **simple, easy to understand, and gives you the quickest results**. The drag & drop components are just what you need and are placed logically to get you going instantly.

The [other applications listed here](https://medium.com/@Mockplus/8-ux-and-ui-wireframe-tools-you-must-try-in-2016-f8fbcccf7f6e#.korkazwt4) give you more refined designs which are kind of prototypes. **Wireframes should look like wireframes** and Balsamiq stands top in this category.

[image]

Comment: This is entirely your subjective opinion. It is not a factual answer. How do you define 'best'? I think what you are referring to is your *favourite*.

Comment: @JonW  I've used a couple of wireframing applications and have found Balsamiq the easiest and fastest till date.

Answer (score 0):

I have had my fair share of using wireframing and mockup tools.

[Proto.io](http://proto.io/) and [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/) top the list for me.
If you want to step it up a notch, [Invision](https://www.invisionapp.com/) is good too.

Answer (score 0):

A good wireframing tool is simply the one that you feel comfortable using for the job you're trying to do.

The first thing I take into account is compatibility with the rest of the team. After that, I have several that I use for different scales of wireframing: If I'm trying to get something done rapidly then I'll use Illustrator as it's something I've been using for almost 20 years - I can work rapidly to build quick sketches. If I'm looking for something more precise then I might use Sketch - with a few extra plugins, I find it relatively easy to build pixel perfect wireframes that are also easy to convert into simple prototypes. If I'm definitely aiming for prototypes with a high level of interactivity then I'll go straight for Axure - there's very little integration with Axure so it requires a lot of work up front to get to a position where the prototypes look good as well as working well so it's good to get started on this as soon as you know the depth of the prototype required.

The softwares listed here are my personal favourites and do not constitute a recommendation - what you need to pay attention to is the reasoning behind choosing a wireframing tool for a particular job: because it's compatible with the rest of your team, because it's quick, because it's precise, or because it offers things further down the line. If you can find one that suits you for each of these (or even all four) then go for it. Although you may find you need to be more flexible to meet various team needs.

Answer (score 0):

A fool with a tool is still a fool....

A wireframe is nothing more than a design communication tool. They are ideal for explaining how you want to things to look and feel, quickly and easily. Wireframes can be low visual fidelity or high visual fidelity.

Some wireframe tools allow you to create simple and complex interactions, which allows you to use them in usability testing.

There are quite a few good wireframing tools, and each comes with their own pros and cons, and each has its ardent supporters.

My best advice is to try and use a few trials of them to see which ones work best for your unique situation.

I currently use a combination of paper prototypes and Axure. Axure meets my needs because I can start with low visual fidelity interactive and move to more complex high visual interactive fairly quickly. Axure gives me more flexibility.

However, I have also used Balsamiq, Visio, PowerPoint, Word, whiteboards, beer mats and napkins - basically I don't get hung up about the tools, I only focus on communicating my design intentions, so will use whatever meets the needs and constraints, and depends heavily on who will be receiving the design.